# Homebrew dependency list differs from dependency tree

Tags: python, homebrew

I wanted to remove `python@3.9` in Homebrew since I use `python@3.10` more often, but Homebrew returned the following error:

```
Error: Refusing to uninstall /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.14
because it is required by cairo and libass, which are currently installed.
You can override this and force removal with:
  brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies python@3.9
```

Okay, so `cairo` and `libass` require `python@3.9` to work... right?

When I ran `brew deps cairo`, it returned the following:

```
ca-certificates
cairo
fontconfig
freetype
fribidi
gdbm
gettext
glib
gobject-introspection
graphite2
harfbuzz
icu4c
libffi
libpng
libpthread-stubs
libx11
libxau
libxcb
libxdmcp
libxext
libxrender
lzo
mpdecimal
openssl@1.1
pcre
pixman
pkg-config
python@3.9
readline
sqlite
xorgproto
xz
```

But when I added the `--tree` flag, it returned the following:

```
cairo
├── fontconfig
│   └── freetype
│       └── libpng
├── freetype
│   └── libpng
├── glib
│   ├── gettext
│   └── pcre
├── libpng
├── libx11
│   ├── libxcb
│   │   ├── libpthread-stubs
│   │   │   └── pkg-config
│   │   ├── libxau
│   │   │   └── xorgproto
│   │   └── libxdmcp
│   │       └── xorgproto
│   └── xorgproto
├── libxcb
│   ├── libpthread-stubs
│   │   └── pkg-config
│   ├── libxau
│   │   └── xorgproto
│   └── libxdmcp
│       └── xorgproto
├── libxext
│   ├── libx11
│   │   ├── libxcb
│   │   │   ├── libpthread-stubs
│   │   │   │   └── pkg-config
│   │   │   ├── libxau
│   │   │   │   └── xorgproto
│   │   │   └── libxdmcp
│   │   │       └── xorgproto
│   │   └── xorgproto
│   └── xorgproto
├── libxrender
│   ├── libx11
│   │   ├── libxcb
│   │   │   ├── libpthread-stubs
│   │   │   │   └── pkg-config
│   │   │   ├── libxau
│   │   │   │   └── xorgproto
│   │   │   └── libxdmcp
│   │   │       └── xorgproto
│   │   └── xorgproto
│   └── xorgproto
├── lzo
└── pixman
```

Notice how `python@3.9` isn't in the dependency tree?

`libass` was the same; the dependency **list** included `python@3.9`, but the dependency **tree** did not.

The Homebrew documentation for [cairo](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/cairo) and [libass](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/libass) seems to follow the dependency tree information (albeit only showing the top-level leaves), and `python@3.9` doesn't seem to appear anywhere.

It'd be helpful if someone could explain the difference in the outputs and whether it is safe for me to remove `python@3.9` despite the warning.

By the way, I don't use `cairo` and `libass`; they are just dependencies for `ffmpeg`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in homebrew. See:
https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/13717

Hope they fix it eventually...